# How do I properly pass events between Fragments without involving Activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a fragment A which starts another fragment B, then the user does something in said fragment, then is closes (by means of the back stack) and the result is returned back to the fragment A.

If I chose to do so with Activities, that would be pretty much straightforward: override `onActivityResult` and call `startActivityForResult` in the first one, and then use `setResult` in the second one to pass the result back right before finishing.

But with fragments, there seems to be no proper way to do this sort of thing (at least I didn't find it).
The one way is to set some sort of callback on the second fragment, call it when the user is done with it and then the first fragment would process the result. It looks like a good solution and I even implemented it, however, it likely won't survive in the event when the host Activity gets destroyed and then restored by the system since there's no way to serialize said callback into a bundle.
The other way is to implement the callback in the Activity and then do something like `((Callback)getActivity()).onEvent(myEvent)` in the fragment. This is infeasible for me as the result needs to be delivered to another fragment, not the activity, and, furthermore, the activity doesn't even know where to direct that event.
Some suggest to do so using `setArguments`, but that won't work for me since I need to pass the event at the point in time when both fragments have already been created.
And, finally, there's `LocalBroadcastManager` but that seems like a huge overkill for such a thing...

So, how do other people do this? I can't be the only one who needs to do this.

Comment: *...the activity doesn't even know where to direct that event.* - the activity is the one holding the fragments so it knows about all of them. You could look at making the last fragment as a nested fragment inside the first fragment, In this case you're safe against activity destruction and it would be easy to let the two fragments communicate as the nested fragment has a reference to its parent fragment through getParentFragment().

Comment: @Luksprog the only thing the Activity does is it sets a FrameLayout as its content view and then puts an initial fragment inside it. Everything else is handled by the fragments themselves.

Answer (score 0):

SharedPreferences.
Fragment A can save the Data to the SharedPreference and Fragment B can just read the Values from it. 
The Values can then be cleared if there is no need to keep.

Comment: Okay, how do I let the other fragment know that it should read these values right now?

Comment: Also, it's even more overkill compared to a LocalBroadcastManager. SharedPreferences are not meant for communication between parts of the app, they're for storing data persistently across app restarts and system reboots.

Comment: You can configure FragmentB to always check sharePreference first

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if i understand your needs perfectly but you can use OttoBus for passing events. Here you can find it from:

http://square.github.io/otto/